# Consistent migration to Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a huge and complicated web application on RoR and I want to migrate its front-end to Twitter Bootstrap. But the revolutionary way (just remove my old CSS then enable Bootstrap and write a new CSS) in unacceptable because it will break the app and the recovery of its functionality will be a very hard work and it will take too much time.

So I'm looking for a consistent way to enable Bootstrap for front-end features one by one having remaining features to look and work in old style until they will be migrated.

Does anybody have resembling experience?

Answer (score 2):

1. Use a CSS pre-processor
2. Turn your existing CSS into .less or Sass
3. Import your file at the end of the .less or Sass version of
   Bootstrap master file (Bootstrap.less)
4. Remove all .less or Sass files from Bootstrap.less
5. Add components as needed back to the Bootstrap.less and build your CSS file.